# change variable inside firebase.databse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function and call firebase database, i want get value and pass to variable declate inside function but don't work. How do this?

```
subObjectTable(data, cell) {
    ...
    const database = fire.database();
    let nome;
    database
    .ref(`/proprietários/${getProp}`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      nome = data.Nome;
    })
    console.log('nome', nome) // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase APIs are asynchronous and return immediately.  The results of your query will be delivered some time later with the results of your query.  `subObjectTable` will have fully completed by the time the first callback occurs.

If you want to do something with the value of `nome`, you'll have to do it *inside* the function callback that you pass to `on()`, or call some other function from there.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you! but how make return line by line? I have any actions before of database. I add new function and pass the value but don't work

Comment: You can't do that.  The best you can do is return a promise that resolves with the data from the database, and make the caller use the promise to register another callback to get the value.  once() already returns a promise this, and is appropriate for getting data a single time.  Consider using that instead.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once